# How to test EJB on local

Tags: java, jsp, ejb

New to EJB, please help:

To verify my EJB on local, I tried create a test.jsp that calls the EJB like this:

```
<%@ page import="com.web.ejb.service.ContentInfo" %>
<% ContentInfo ci = ContentInfo.getContentById("123"); %>
```

When run the jsp, got error "Only a type can be imported. com.web.ejb.service.ContentInfo resolves to a package".

Then I replaced the import with

```
<jsp:useBean id="ContentInfo" class="com.web.ejb.service.ContentInfo" />
```

but got "ContentInfo cannot be resolved to a type."

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, seems like `com.web.ejb.service.ContentInfo` is not your class name. Maybe you made a typo ?

If you want to test an EJB more thoroughly, you can use [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) to replicate the functionalities of an EJB server, in case of units tests for example.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the class name is correct and it is available in the above mentioned package. After that try this:

```
<%@ page import="<package>.<YourBusinessInterface>, javax.naming.*"%>

<%!
try {
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
   <YourBusinessInterface> obj = (<YourBusinessInterface>)
                ic.lookup(<YourBusinessInterface>.class.getName());

} catch (Exception ex) {
    // exception code here    
}
%>

<html>
   <body>
      <% obj.callBusinessMethod(); %>
   </body>
</html>
```

This link http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbnp.html might help you.  :)